# Laravel passport oauth/authorize error

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm trying to use Passport using the oauth/authorize in order to allow web application to get the code and request token later, but I'm getting the error

> Route [login] not defined

Below is my code.

Client code

```
    // First route that user visits on consumer app
Route::get('/', function () {
    // Build the query parameter string to pass auth information to our request
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => 3,
        //'client_secret' => 'MtkEmBL0f0Bf4LcEPcOBUS0wLHvF5xqqchhCpaTH',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://client.app:8082/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => ''
    ]);

    // Redirect the user to the OAuth authorization page
    return redirect('http://server.app:8082/oauth/authorize?' . $query);
});


// Route that user is forwarded back to after approving on server
Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
    return 'test 2';
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://server.app:8082/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => 3, // from admin panel above
            'client_secret' => 'MtkEmBL0f0Bf4LcEPcOBUS0wLHvF5xqqchhCpaTH', // from admin panel above
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://client.app:8082/callback',
            'code' => $request->code // Get code from the callback
        ]
    ]);

    // echo the access token; normally we would save this in the DB
    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
});
```

[image: oauth/authorize request error]

[image: oauth/authorize request error]

Comment: Where do you define auth routes?

Comment: Hi shukshin! My routes are defined in AuthServiceProvider File, like bellow..      Passport::routes();

Comment: Question, where have you defined /oauth/authorize route? I'm using oneAuth client for a more complex scenario but this part of the flow applies to my case as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have more than one error. Looks like you forgot to define common auth routes. Start from `php artisan make:auth` or `Auth::routes()`. OAuth routes doesn't have `login` route, the error you've got says you didn't define `login` route. It is defined in `Auth::routes()` actually.

Comment: But php artisan make:auth will create the scaffolding templates for user login, register and etc, but it's an api, so it shouldn't have html pages, instead, it should retorn the authorize page in order for the user to give permission for the app so it can request a token after user's permission...

Comment: So just add `Auth::routes()` into your routes file if you don't need its views\layouts.

Comment: Wait, if you have Passport installed, it means, that user can sign in to the website. Being signed in, the user accepts oauth request from another service. How do you suppose he accept oauth request otherwise?

Comment: Well, correct me please if i'm wrong, but, the client (My Web App) will send the client_id and secret to the API (Oauth) , the API will then return the Permission page, where it's up for the user to deny or accept the Web App to request a token, if so, the user will type the email and passoword wich will be send through a post request along with the client_secret, id and the grant_type password, then the API will return the access token.. Is that right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure how it works when user is not authorized on OAuth provider server. Anyhow, your OAuth server has all users, all the auth logic and login form as well. That's why it is essential to have auth routes. User must be logged in to accept\deny authorization request.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, apparently, i wasn't passing the Accept header in the request

```
Accept:application/json
```